# Is it possible to populate a viewmodel and form error messages via ViewData[]?

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core-mvc, partial-views

(**Update:** I found out that the `Model` in a view is read-only, so my initial idea of populating the model properties via ViewData is not possible. Any other workaround?)

I have some CRUD-functionality as partial views. If the submitted form is invalid, I'm not able to redisplay the form with the incomplete data. Can it be done?

In my main view for a project (Details.cshtml), I have this to display the notes of that project:

```
<partial name="_notes" model="@new ProjectNotesViewModel 
{ 
    ProjectId = Model.Id,
    Notes = Model.Notes, 
    ProjectNoteId = Model.ProjectNoteId, 
    ProjectNoteAction = Model.ProjectNoteAction,
    ProjectCompleted = Model.Completed
}" />
```

This is the controller method "Details()" for a project:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id, int n, string a)
// n = ProjectNoteId, a = ProjectNoteAction ("c"=create, "e"=edit, "d"=delete, "v"=view (details))
{
    Project project = await db.Projects
        .Include(n => n.Notes)
        .Include(p => p.ParentProject)
        .Include(c => c.ChildProjects)
            .ThenInclude(o => o.ProjectOwner)
        .Include(o => o.ProjectOwner)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);

    if (project == null) { return NotFound(); }

    ProjectViewModel vm = auto.Map<ProjectViewModel>(project);
    vm.ProjectNoteId = n;
    vm.ProjectNoteAction = a;
    vm.ProjectCompletedAction = a;
    return View(vm);
}
```

The partial "_notes.cshtml" equates to Index.cshtml for project notes.

In _notes.cshtml, I have this:

```
@foreach (ProjectNoteViewModel note in Model.Notes)
{
    if (note.Id == Model.ProjectNoteId)
    {
        // Then we want to do something to this particular note:
        <tr class="alert-black-50">
            <td class="align-text-top text-light rounded-left" width="1">
                <span class="fas fa-clipboard fa-fw"></span>
            </td>
            <td class="pb-2 pr-2 text-light rounded-right">
                @if (Model.ProjectNoteAction == "v") // v = view (details)
                {
                    // View the details of the note
                    <partial name="_noteDetails" model="@note" />
                }
                @if (Model.ProjectNoteAction == "e") // = edit
                {
                    // Edit the note
                    <partial name="_noteEdit" model="@note" />
                }
                @if (Model.ProjectNoteAction == "d") // = delete
                {
                    // Delete the note
                    <partial name="_noteDelete" model="@note" />
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    else
    {
        // Just display the date and title:
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <a asp-action="Details" 
                    asp-route-n="@note.Id" 
                    asp-route-a="v">
                    <span class="fas fa-clipboard fa-fw"></span>
                    @note.Created &ndash; @note.Title
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

If we for instance want to create a new project note, this is where that happens ("_noteCreate.cshtml"):

```
@model Projects.Models.ProjectNoteViewModel

<form asp-action="CreateNote">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="ProjectId" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Title" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Contents" class="control-label"></label>
        <textarea asp-for="Contents" class="form-control"></textarea>
        <span asp-validation-for="Contents" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@Model.ProjectId" class="btn btn-primary btn-split">
            <span class="fas fas-split fa-chevron-circle-left fa-fw"></span> Cancel
        </a>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-split">
            <span class="fas fas-split fa-save fa-fw"></span> Save
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

The "CreateNote" controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateNote(int projectId, [Bind("Title,Contents")] ProjectNote note)
{
    Project project = await db.Projects.Where(p => p.Id == projectId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    if (project == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    if (project.Completed)
    {
        // Prevent new notes from being created on completed projects.
        return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = project.Id });
    }
    note.ProjectId = projectId;
    note.Created = DateTime.Now;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Add(note);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = projectId });
    }

    ProjectNoteViewModel vm = auto.Map<ProjectNoteViewModel>(note);
    vm.Project = auto.Map<ProjectViewModel>(project);
    ViewData["draft"] = vm; // Can I somehow populate the form from ViewData?
    return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = projectId });
    //return View(vm); // I can't do this, because there is no "CreateNote.cshtml"
}
```

The last five lines of the above method is what I can't figure out. In a normal CRUD-situation, where the name of the controller method would be `Create()`, and we had a view called "Create.cshtml", this would be the way to do it:

```
ProjectNoteViewModel vm = auto.Map<ProjectNoteViewModel>(note);
vm.Project = auto.Map<ProjectViewModel>(project);
return View(vm);
```

But I can't `return View()`, because there is no view called "CreateNote". I need to bring the user back to "Projects/Details/5?a=c", where `a=c` (action=create) indicates that we are creating a new note on that project. And I want to bring the incomplete form data with me.

Comment: You can say "return View("~/MyPath/ToTheView/MCcooView.csthmll", MyCoolModel)" and pass the model as the second parameter.

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro "The view '~/Projects/Details.cshtml?id=1&a=c' was not found."

Comment: You need to use a real path not a URL..... So it would be the actual folder like "~/RootOfMyProject/Views/Details.csthml" or something like that

Comment: also you do NOT need to pass query string parameters.... because you can pass the MODEL to the View... so you do not need any query string parameters...

Comment: But to be honest your MVC design seems to be wrong... In any case what you can do is do not post the entire page back... just use javascript to async post your CreateNote form and get back the partial view or JSON and "refresh" the screen....

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro Ok, I got to the view, but Details.cshtml uses a different viewmodel than _noteCreate.cshtml. A project viewmodel contains a list of notes. Do I have to make changes to the viewmodel, and add a single note too?

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro Yes, some ajax functionality would be nice. But I haven't done that before. I have thought about it on this project, as it would be a perfect case for it.

Comment: If you are going to serve the view... you need to reconstruct the view with what you want to return